# Is $a_n={\{\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{3^n}}\}$is monotonically decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is $a_n={\{\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{3^n}}\}$is monotonically decreasing?

In process of solving this problem, I faced to the problem of proving that

$A::$:  $\dfrac{2k+1}{(k(k+1))^2}-\dfrac{4}{3^{k+1}}\geq 0$ for every positive odd integer $k>1$,

which will complete the proof that ${\{a_n}\}$ would be monotonically decreasing.

Even induction method makes it more complicated. Is statement $A$ holds?

Thank you.

Comment: Calculate the first few values, and check whether they are decreasing.

Comment: ${\{0.666, 0.361, 0.074, 0.075, ...}\}$. It's not monotone! Thank you.

Comment: How would one prove this analytically though?

Comment: @Uzman I suppose, calculate $a_4 - a_3$ as a fraction and check that it's positive.

Comment: @Uzman: If it is monotonically decreasing, then for every index $n$, we must have $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$. Thus, ${\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}}\leq {\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{3^n}}$; this is true if $n$ is even, and for $n$ as an odd it's on the question.

Comment: But still problem remains: How to face a contradiction analytically that $\dfrac{2k+1}{(k(k+1))^2}-\dfrac{4}{3^{k+1}}\geq 0$, doesn't hold for every odd $k>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note first that $$\dfrac{2k+1}{(k(k+1))^2}\geqslant \dfrac{2k}{k^2(k+1)^2}= \dfrac{2}{k(k+1)^2}\geqslant \dfrac{2}{(k+1)^3}$$
If we prove that
$$\dfrac{1}{n^3}\geqslant \dfrac{2}{3^n} \tag{1}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\dfrac{3^n}{n^3} \geqslant  2 \tag{2}$$
then we can conclude that
$$\dfrac{2k+1}{(k(k+1))^2}-\dfrac{4}{3^{k+1}}\geqslant 0.$$
The inequality $(2)$ holds for sufficiently large $n,\;\;(n\geqslant{6})$ and can be proved by induction.

Comment: Thank you. I proved it for $n\geq 6\implies \dfrac{3^n}{n^3}\geq2$, by induction. And, it can also be seen on the graph of $f(x) = \dfrac{3^x}{x^3}-2$, for some extent of $x$. So, ${\{a_n}\}$ is monotonically decreasing for $n\geq 6$.